# Looking for QMenu real position

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, position, qmenu

I have some problem to locate my QMenu at runtime.
`menu->pos()` is supposed to send his position back, but it sends `QPoint(0,0)`. To find its real position I have to open that menu and hover a QAction.

Is there a way to initialize correct menu position without opening manually that menu?

The idea is showing the user where (s)he can find an option, and using `exec` or `popup` without correct position is not helping…

`mainwindow.cpp`  (`QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11`)

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QMenu>
#include <QMenuBar>

#include <QDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    QMenuBar * menuBar = new QMenuBar(this);
    QMenu    * menu    = new QMenu("File", this);

    menu->addAction("Action0");

    menuBar->addMenu(menu);

    qDebug() << menu->pos();

    connect(menu, &QMenu::hovered, this, [menu] {
        qDebug() << menu->pos();
    });

    setMenuBar(menuBar);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{

}
```

`mainwindow.h`

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
 };

 #endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

`main.cpp`

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: *To find its real position* - What do you mean by **real position**? As the Qt docs state for [pos](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#pos-prop): *"This property holds the position of the widget within its parent widget."* So it's returning correctly, as its position is (0,0) relative to the MainWindow.

Comment: As you can see on this image: https://lut.im/FRDsH1pu/xNdjjPg5 ,
the first `pos()` returns `QPoint(0,0)`, but after hovering the action in the menu `pos()` returns the menu position on the screen.

I would like to get that position directly.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not quite sure what you're asking by *'get that position directly'*. It looks like you're getting the positions you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Mmm... I know it is a *bit* late, but, two things:

1. As the menu bar is created in the constructor, it doesn't have any position assigned yet, you'd have to query the position later (the `moveEvent` may be a good place and you have updated that position if the window moves).
2. If such position is still relative to the parent window, you can use [`QMenuBar::mapToGlobal`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#mapToGlobal) to map the local position to screen coordinates.